# compressed assets serving and setting expirations on them in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am pre-compressing assets (js and css) and I store these files ending in `.gz` alongside the originals in the directory `/build`. Serving the compressed static assets works when I add to my nginx config:

```
location /build {
  gzip_static on;
}
```

I also try to set a caching policy for all my assets (in all directories) with adding this to my config (below the previous code):

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf)$ {
  expires 30d;
  access_log off;
}
```

This is also working. However, my compressed `.gz` files are now no longer served. Removing `gz` from the selector does not change anything. Why does this happen and how can I serve my compressed files while also setting an expiration for my assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one `location` block will be selected by nginx, with [matching regular expression locations preferred over static prefixes](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).  Thus, when a static asset is being served, the `location ~* <etc>` block is being used, which doesn't include the `gzip_static on` setting.  Copy that into the static assets block and it'll all Just Work again.